# access all images oustside documentRoot not workng Apache windows

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, document-root

when a User upload Images, I have a folder outside my **documentRoot** which save it. I have tried to loop through all the images and show them but it is not working. php apache alias.
I have not hosted the website yet.

alias conf

```
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /webdev "c:\exclusive\webdev"
```

testing it within my documentRoot php
my document root location
C:\xampp\htdocs\create
The alias root location
C:\exclusive\webdev

```
$path = '/webdev';
    $ImgDir = webdev/;
     $files = new FilesystemIterator($path);
     $images = new RegexIterator($files, '/\.(?:jpg|png|gif|webp)$/i');
     foreach ($images as $image) { 
        
        $fie =$image->getFilename();
        echo '<img src="',$ImgDir, $fie,'" width="300"/>';
}
```

Comment: Where is `$path` defined in `$files = new FilesystemIterator( $path );`?

Comment: `$ImgDir = webdev/;` this line should cause error, there are missing quotes, also the path is relative like `src="webdev/test.jpg"`, if your php file is in folder or routed to similar look, for example `localhost/test/` then the final link is `localhost/test/webdev/test.jpg` which is not accessible

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i have edit the code i did a mistake typing

Comment: @Kazz thank you . which means i can't read images outside the document root?

Comment: @QuobiSlim you can, you just have to use absolute path like `$ImgDir = '/webdev/';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without testing you can probably use the absolute path to the source files and then the alias to display the images.

```
$path = 'c:\\exclusive\\webdev';
$ImgDir = '/webdev';

$files = new FilesystemIterator( $path );
$images = new RegexIterator( $files, '/\.(?:jpg|png|gif|webp)$/i' );

foreach( $images as $image ) {
    printf( '<img src="%s/%s" width="300"/>', $ImgDir, $image->getFilename() );
}
```

Comment: wow. it work. I apricate your time and your knowledge.

Comment: glad that it helped